# How to improve upload speed of files using html form and PHP?

Tags: php, performance, mobile, server, mobile-website

I have a web application (PHP/MySQL) that allows users to upload files to the server via website with a simple form (I'm not using any plugins). This website can be accessed through mobile devices. My issue is the speed in which these files are sent if you use mobile 4G because users complain that it's too slow.

I'm wondering how is it possible that you can send files through WhatsApp/LINE and they're sent in seconds while sending the same files using this website can take even minutes using the same network 4G.

Does it have to do with the server where the website is hosted?

Are there any specifications for the server that could allow it to be faster? Bandwidth maybe?

Or, is there any plugin that I could use (jquery maybe) to upload files faster?

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: pay for a host with more bandwidth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could test the upload speed on your local network on a computer, if the issues happens also, the connection to your server will be the problem.

If the connection to your server is speedfull enought. The 4G network is the problem.

Many messengers like WhatsApp are reducing the quality of images for example before they are uploaded.
So the amount of data gets smaller.